# Python Variable List Name in .Append

Tags: python, python-2.7

To lead out I am aware this is a bad idea. Dictionaries are looking like a cleaner way of doing what I need to do but I'm looking for a place holder to hold things in piece while I figure out how to use dictionaries properly for what I need.

In the meantime I have about a dozen lists and I'm trying to set the list name to use with a variable.

So normally I'd use:

```
Listname.Append("Text")
```

But on different iterations of a loop I want to be able to use a different list which is being split from a larger string.

Something like:

```
x1 = []
x2 = []
x3 = []

for y in 1 to 3:
    "x"+y.append("string")
```

Again, I know this is a bad idea and I'm trying to get my head around dictionaries but this would be the equivalent of duct tape to hold things together while I do that.

I can't figure out a way to get this to work. It tells me that .append doesn't work with that (which I expected). I tried converting the whole thing with str() on a long shot but it of course told me you don't append to a string.

I get this is probably not something you want to do commonly and if I do manage it by IDE is going to yell at me for doing stupid things but is it possible in the first place?

Comment: It will be easier to understand dictionaries compared to all the answers that will be posted for your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any answer to your question will be more difficult to understand than dictionaries themselves. Anyway, here it goes.

If your lists are global, they are stored in a dictionary returned by built-in function `globals()`. So you can fetch those lists from that dictionary and then append to them.

So you can do:

```
x1 = []
x2 = []
x3 = []

for y in range(1, 4):
    x = globals()['x' + str(y)]
    x.append("string")
```

Comment: I knew this was ugly but cheers guys duct tape applied. Now I'll have to learn to do things properly before something catches fire.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries are indeed the far superior solution. However, if you *desperately* need a work-around, you could leverage [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals):

```
x1 = []
x2 = []
x3 = []

for y in 1 to 3:
    locals()["x"+str(y)].append("string")
```

This has the side benefit of being easily replaceable with a `dict` later, since you are actually using something `dict`-like.

To be honest, though, replacing with `dict` just [isn't that hard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35664523/1394393) in this case.

I can imagine some situations that would complicate the matter, though:

There is also a similar [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) if the variables are in module scope and this is in a function.

If these are attributes on a class or an object, you can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
class X(object):
    x1 = []
    x2 = []
    x3 = []

for y in 1 to 3:
    getattr(X, "x"+str(y)).append("string")

class Z(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x1 = []
        self.x2 = []
        self.x3 = []

z = Z()
for y in 1 to 3:
    getattr(z, "x"+str(y)).append("string")
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the variables into a dictionary. Lists are one of those objects that are passed by reference, because a list is a reference to a complex object. Therefore, if you put it in a dictionary, you can still refer to it as `x1`, but you can also refer to it as `d["x1"]`, so long as you don't delete it or reinitialize it using `x1 = []`.

```
my_lists = {}
my_lists["x1"] = x1
my_lists["x2"] = x2
my_lists["x3"] = x3

for y in range(1,4):
    listname = "x" + str(y)
    my_lists[listname].append("string")
```

Comment: Missing a `)` at the end.

Comment: _To lead out I am aware this is a bad idea. Dictionaries are looking like a cleaner way of doing what I need to do but..._

Comment: @zondo, so this makes a good transition, right? Use dictionary with some lists, then transition over to dictionary only, as modules get refactored.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries associate objects to other objects. They're not the worst thing to learn in Python.

```
x = {}

for y in range(1, 4):
    if y not in x:
        # create array for entry y in x if it does not exist
        x[y] = []

    x[y].append('string')
```

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone else has said, dictionaries are what you want.  I suppose if you really wanted to use lists only, you could do it like this:

```
x_lst = [[], [], []]

for i in range(3):
    x_lst[i].append('string')

x1, x2, x3 = x_lst[0], x_lst[1], x_lst[2]

In [52]: x1, x2, x3
Out[52]: (['string'], ['string'], ['string'])
```

But, this is much more confusing than just learning to use dictionaries, which are pretty easy to grasp.